# Toggle Class not working in hover in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what i need

- i need to toggle image when after click using toggleclass.

  css code

  ```
   .favourate{ display:block; background:url('/images/star1.png') no-repeat; width:24px; height:25px; float:right;}
    .favourate.faved, .favourate:active{ background:url('/images/star1_hover.png') no-repeat; transition:.2s ease all;}
  ```

javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var eventData = {};
if (localStorage.getItem('eventData') !== null) {
    $.each(eventData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('eventData')), function(id){
        $('#'+id).addClass('faved');
    });
}
$('.favourate_dextop').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (eventData[this.id] !== undefined) {
        delete eventData[this.id];
    }else{
        eventData[this.id] = $(this).data();
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('faved');
    localStorage.setItem('eventData', JSON.stringify(eventData));
    console.log(eventData);
});  
     });
```

what i have tried

- i have tried remove hover in css & then toggle class work fine.
  jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xxuhL555/
- here is jsfiddle of when i not removed hover in css :http://jsfiddle.net/o61rqj95/
- how could i handle this issue through css or jquery.
- is this problem of toggleclass or css.

debug

- on click image changes.
- and re click on red star noting (images do"nt changes ).
- on removing hover it works that is not my requirement.

output

- it should be like toggling of images without removing hover from images.

Comment: nothing is working , background images changes onclick but it doesnot changes again

Comment: It works fine for me too, I get no errors in chrome or firefox, and the image changes and changes back when I click. What browser+version are you using?

Comment: check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/o61rqj95/

Comment: me to check with chrome & mozilla nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, the Fiddles throw an error on the localStorage code, preventing the click handler from being registered. The click event code by itself works fine.

Comment: image not toggling  http://jsfiddle.net/o61rqj95/ , nothing is working  in chorme onc e image is toggled it is not toggled back.

Comment: fiddles does not throws error , this is not error i mean to say , on hover click works (images changes),:fine , now again click on red star does it seems to toggle no its not ..that i was talking about...